# Adding a Project Reference to a Xamarin Forms App

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

VS 2017 / C#.

I have a working Web and WebApi app.  A web page accessing the WebApi (both written by me). I am now trying to create a Mobile App using Xamarin forms to call the WebApi.  My mobile app needs access to a DTO project (part of my API).  I can add the reference to the xxx.Android App, but I need to reference the DTO's in the xxx.Mobile App.  There seems to be no option to add a reference in that 'shared' app.  This means my code error's as it cannot find the DTO definitions.

Anyone have advice?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to right-click the Dependencies of the Forms project and add the reference.[image]

Comment: Haha, I had the same confusion the first time I worked on a .NET Core lib. Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

OK - slightly embarrassing, but will post in case others have this issue.
There is no "References" under the Project.  However, if you right-click the Project, there is an option to add a Reference.  It then creates it.