# Add Reference option missing from Dependencies in Xamarin Forms (.NET Standard 2)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I am trying to add a reference to my Xamarin Forms project but the option is missing for some reason.

I am  using Visual Studio 2019 version: 16.6.2

[[image: https://imgur.com/a/CDkG6qc]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPMJX.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dll file, simply browse for it and peform a manual reference.

Comment: I do have the DLL file, but the "Add Reference" button isn't there. I'll upload a screenshot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371166/11731800 - Check this out. Might help you out.

Comment: Nope, the option isn't there either.

Comment: Add Project Reference - Browse - Select the dll - OK